# Changing Toolbar text color

Tags: android, material-design, toolbar

I am trying to change the text color of the toolbar,but at no vail. Here is my code.

**styles.xml**

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="BasicTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

</style>
<style name="ToolbarTheme" parent="BasicTheme">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_color</item>
</style>
```

**tool_lay**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar     
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:appo="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
   android:id="@+id/toolbar"
   android:elevation="10dp"
   android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
   appo:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"
 >
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

tools:context="testing.theo.aelfootballclub.MainActivity"
android:background="#3d827e">
<include

    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/tool_lay"

    />
<LinearLayout
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:background="#6e7398"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/user_name"
        android:hint="Userame"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/user_pass"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:hint="Κωδικός"
        />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Εισοδος"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="userLogin"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Εγγραφη"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:onClick="userReg"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Ξεχασες τον κωδικό?"
        android:id="@+id/forgotPass"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and finally my **MainActivity**.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Toolbar toolbar;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setToolbar();
}
private void setToolbar(){
    toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
  }

}
```

The background color of the toolbar works fine. I can change it to any color I want to.

Any ideas,

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do like this

```
private void setToolbar(){
    toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitleTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(),R.color.yellow));
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
  }
```

Comment: It throughs me an exception. Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0xffffff00

Answer (score 2):

In your `ToolbarTheme` override `titleTextAppearance` style:

```
<style name="ToolbarTheme" parent="BasicTheme">
    <item name="titleTextAppearance">@style/ToolbarTheme.Title</item>
</style>

<style name="ToolbarTheme.Title" parent="TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">{your_color}</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the xml attribute for changing text color in toolbar

```
app:titleTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
       Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        // Title and subtitle
        toolbar.setTitle(R.string.about_toolbar_title);
        toolbar.setSubtitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        toolbar.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(
                R.color.themeToolbarColor));
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_back);
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

In Your theme add this,

```
  <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/actionMenuTextColor</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Zagórski's answer changes the theme for the title, while you can set just the title text color: Instead of defining `android:textColor`, set `android:textColorPrimary`.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your themes.xml file

```
<style name="Theme.YourAppName" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use this line for androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar:

```
 app:titleTextColor="@color/yourColor"
```